# this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key username

Tags: swift3

[this is my project file](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=22007904213298677995) I'm a beginner and this is my first app, so please explain simply.
I have checked my usernameTextField connection to @IBOutlet, even deleted it and reconnected for many times but still same error:

2017-04-19 21:34:27.957164+0430 Cactus-LoginRegister[774:12760] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/shamymash/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/19D0A023-F7CC-4813-B35E-1452B3BA4F07/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2017-04-19 21:34:27.957557+0430 Cactus-LoginRegister[774:12760] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
2017-04-19 21:34:35.582 Cactus-LoginRegister[774:12760] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key username.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104fd6b0b **exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000104a3b141 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104fd6a59 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x0000000104619731 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForUndefinedKey:] + 226
    4   Foundation                          0x0000000104548e1d -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] + 284
    5   Cactus-LoginRegister                0x0000000104458394 _TFC20Cactus_LoginRegister26RegisterPageViewController20registerButtonTappedfP_T_ + 3092
    6   Cactus-LoginRegister                0x00000001044595c3 _TToFC20Cactus_LoginRegister26RegisterPageViewController20registerButtonTappedfP_T_ + 67
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001053fbd22 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010558025c -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000105580577 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010557f4b2 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 618
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010546949a -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2707
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010546abb0 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4114
    13  UIKit                               0x00000001054177b0 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 352
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000105bfaadc __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2926
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000105bf2a3a __handleEventQueue + 1122
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104f7cc01 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104f620cf __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 527
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104f615ff __CFRunLoopRun + 911
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104f61016 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001095b4a24 GSEventRunModal + 62
    21  UIKit                               0x00000001053fa0d4 UIApplicationMain + 159
    22  Cactus-LoginRegister                0x0000000104456ba7 main + 55
    23  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010864965d start + 1
    24  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

class RegisterPageViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var usernameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var repeatPasswordTextField: UITextField!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



@IBAction func registerButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    let username = usernameTextField.text
    let password = passwordTextField.text
    let repeatPassword = repeatPasswordTextField.text


    //Check for empty fields

    if (username!.isEmpty || password!.isEmpty || repeatPassword!.isEmpty) {

        //Display alert

        displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage: "All fields are required!")

        return
    }

    //Check if passwords match

    if(password != repeatPassword){

        //Display an alert

        displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage: "Passwords do not match")

        return



    }

    //Store data

    UserDefaults.standard.set(username,forKey: value(forKey: "username") as! String)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(password,forKey: value(forKey: "password") as! String)

    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

    //Display alert message with confirmation

    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Registration has succeeded. Thank you! ", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title:"ok", style:UIAlertActionStyle.default){ action in
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    myAlert.addAction(okAction)
    self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}


func displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage:String) {

    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title:"ok", style:UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:nil)

    myAlert.addAction(okAction)

    self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

Comment: If the error message says it's not compliant for `username` (**not** `usernameTextField`), you likely have a second IBOutlet called `username` lying around that you have to remove in Interface Builder.

Comment: no, not that I can see, is it possible for you to check the project for me plz? I 've attached the file.

Comment: I do not get an error when running your project.  Have you tried using Product->Clean and then building again?

Comment: yes I even deleted the textfield and added it again >clean>rebuild . I also updated Xcode to the latest version.thanks for taking time to check it by the way

Comment: Try downloading your own project again from that URL to some different location on your system and see if you still get an error when you build.  If you still get an error, paste the exact message into your question.

Comment: I get an error in RegisterPageViewController when I tap registerButton

Comment: I see (your question didn't originally say how you reproduced the error).  Why are you using `value(forKey: "username") as! String` instead of just "username"?

Comment: still get the same error after changing that line: 

UserDefaults.standard.set(username,forKey: "username")

Comment: @ShamyMash  Are you sure it's the same or are you getting a similar one for "password" now?

Comment: yes it was for the password and it works just fine now. my bad. thanks a bunch